# "Could not find a suitable constructor" when extracted interface from my resource class with Jersey 2

Tags: java, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

How can I make Jersey understand that it should use a concrete class instead of the interface for a resource?

I had a working app with a `Status` resource. Then I extracted an interface `IStatus`, and moved all JAX-RS annotations there. Now, I get:

```
org.glassfish.hk2.api.MultiException A MultiException has 1 exceptions.  They are:1. java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Could not find a suitable constructor in resource.IStatus class
```

I know that this works with RestEasy. Is there any way of making it work with Jersey?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put the class level `@Path` on the implementation instead of the interface. Jersey is trying to instantiate the interface, which it can't.

Comment: That works, but I'd like to keep it in the interface, so that all annotations are together. RestEasy allows that.

Comment: This is by specification (JAX-RS). The fact that RESTeasy allows it, is a feature specific to RESTeasy. Jersey even logs a warning telling you that the interface will be ignored, when you startup the application. I would imagine that the "ignored" would mean that it wouldn't even try to instantiate it, but I guess that's not the case.

Answer (score 8):

To whoever reaches this thread and the above wasn't the issue, in my scenario it was this:

> Please pay special attention to constructors annotated with @Inject. It is a common mistake to import com.google.Inject instead of javax.inject.Inject.

From here:
https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/issues/2390

That solved the issue!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was missing an `@Component` annotation like in the example below:

```java
@Component // <-- this was missing
@Path("/somepath")
public class MyComponent {

    private OtherComponent otherComponent;

    public MyComponent(OtherComponent otherComponent) {
        this.otherComponent = otherComponent;
    }
}
```

Comment: your answer is not related to the question. The question was about JAX-RS (on JavaEE platform) and you post a spring boot example. Also why do you answer to a six year old question, that already has an approved answer?

Comment: I thought it may be useful to someone to who has the same symptoms, but a different cause as the original poster.